# Generar un codigo correlativo en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola comunidad, estoy tratando de generar un codigo correlativo de mi columna `cod_document`, el cual tiene el primer registro con el formato `ORF00000000000`.

¿Cómo podría hacer para que se pueda generar otro código y sea ahora `ORF000000000002` y asi sucesivamente?

Estaba probando con esta sentencia para obtener los caracteres, pero no me incrementa a pesar de en el `MAX` le agregue `+1`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LPAD((MAX(SUBSTRING(cod_document,1,12))+1),12,'0')) as 'codigo' FROM orders;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ORF', LPAD(MAX(SUBSTRING(cod_document, 4))+1, 11, '0')) AS codigo FROM orders;
```

En donde:

- `MAX(SUBSTRING(cod_document, 4))+1, 11`: Nos devuelve el número más alto de la columna `cod_document` y le suma `1`.
- `LPAD(MAX(SUBSTRING(cod_document, 4))+1, 11, '0')`: Le agregamos ceros a la izquierda al número obtenido hasta que tenga 11 dígitos.
- `CONCAT('ORF', LPAD(MAX(SUBSTRING(cod_document, 4))+1, 11, '0'))`: Concatenamos el resultado con la cadena `ORF`.

---

<kbd>[**Demo**](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/ITHJqzC3hQL)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres generar manualmente los SELECTS puedes concatenar tomando los primeros caracteres del String original y luego agregarle el último carácter. Tu problema es muy abierto según que es lo que necesitas, con lo que hay muchos tipo de soluciones.

```
SELECT CONCAT (
       SUBSTRING( 
                 (SELECT cod_document FROM orders) ,  -- el string original
                  1 , -- iniciamos desde el primer carácter
                  LENGTH((SELECT cod_document FROM orders)) - 1) -- el tamaño del string original - 1
                  , 7 -- agregamos el último dígito a elección aquí
                 )
               )
```